# Loop with Multiple counters

Tags: java

I am very new to Java. I've written a program to create 4 json objects in the following format.

```
{"hostname":"host1","username":"user1"}
{"hostname":"host2","username":"user2"}
{"hostname":"host3","username":"user3"}
{"hostname":"host4","username":"user4"}
```

I use two input files hosts.lst and users.lst and store them in a arraylist

```
$ cat hosts.lst
host1
host2
host3
host4
$ cat users.lst
user1
user2
user3
user4
```

Now I want host<\n> to be in the range of "1 to 4"; But user<\n> should not exceed "2". I am not able to do that with nested for loops (I end up creating 4 * 2 = 8 objects). How do I control multiple counters and increment them to different levels. I want the final output to look like:

```
{"hostname":"host1","username":"user1"}
{"hostname":"host2","username":"user2"}
{"hostname":"host3","username":"user1"}
{"hostname":"host4","username":"user2"}
```

Once user counter reaches 2, it should restart from 1.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class JsonGenerator {

private static ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
private static ArrayList<String> hosts = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void arrayListConstructor1(String filename) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        users.add(line);
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    br.close();
}

public static void arrayListConstructor2(String filename) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        hosts.add(line);
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    br.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    for (int counter = 0; counter < 4; counter++) {

        arrayListConstructor1("e:\\users.lst");
        arrayListConstructor2("e:\\hosts.lst");

        String hostname = new String(hosts.get(counter));
        String username = new String(users.get(counter));

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

        obj.put("hostname", hostname);
        obj.put("username", username);

        System.out.print(obj);
        System.out.println("\n");

    }
}}
```

I appreciate any help with this. Thank you!

Comment: on a side note you are reading the contents of file on every loop.. you only need to read the content once, hence you can put that code outside of the   loop... also there is repetition in the methods that read content from file.. you can write just one method for reading data from both files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is now, your code is reading the 2 files 4 time, you should move the `arrayListConstructor1(...)` and `arrayListConstructor2(...)` before the loop, to read them only once. Also, this methods seem to do the same thing, you can have only one method to read the files. And to limit the range of the users list, you can define a second counter and set it to `0` every time it reaches the range's maximum. Here is an example:

```
public static ArrayList<String> arrayListConstructor(String filename) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));) {
        for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            list.add(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> hosts = arrayListConstructor("e:\\\\hosts.lst");
    ArrayList<String> users = arrayListConstructor("e:\\\\users.lst");
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();

    for (int counter = 0, counter2 = 0; counter < hosts.size() && users.size() >= 2; counter++, counter2++) {
        String hostname = hosts.get(counter);
        String username = users.get(counter2);
        if (counter2 == 1) {
            counter2 = 0;
        }

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

        obj.put("hostname", hostname);
        obj.put("username", username);
        arr.put(obj);

        System.out.print(obj);
        System.out.println("\n");

    }
    System.out.print(arr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - this is really helped! Thanks to @redflar3 as well. I am not able to upvote the answers as I am very new to the forum - thank you both!

Comment: @Karthik , I'm glad I could help. You can choose one of the answer as the one that answered your question by clicking the check mark in the top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below code.. we take mod of counter with 2 and add by 1.. so the value will loop between 1 and 2 for an increasing value of counter.

```
String username = new String(users.get((counter % 2) + 1));
```

one other approach would be to pass a limit to the method that read users from file, then the method can read only the required amount of users.

```
arrayListConstructor1("e:\\users.lst", 2);
```